# References not updating from BibTex

Tags: bibtex, texstudio

I have a quick question about updating my references from Bibtex.  I am using TexStudio as my Latex editor.

I have to make changes to some of the references.  I put the changes in the "references.bib" file.  I then compile the Bibtex and the main document I'm working on.  Sometimes the changes show up, and sometimes they don't, and I haven't figured out why. I have even gone as far as trying to delete the references by changing the filename, but the original references still appear.  Here's what I put in my main document:

```
\newpage %Puts in References

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{references}
```

My references.bib file shows all the changes I have made.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: The normal procedure is: (1) save both your `.tex` and `.bib` files(!); (2) `latex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `latex file.tex`, `latex file.tex` (note: strictly speaking, the file extensions are detected automatically, but can be included if you like).  If this is not getting you what you want, it is time to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: Try using an automator like arara

Comment: As jon said, in general you have to call `latex bibtex latex latex`. Do you use the `Build` command of TeXstudio? This should make all required calls. If not, an example would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks!  I compiled the Latex file twice and deleted the temporary files, and that seemed to do it.

Answer (score 14):

Sometimes you need delete all temporary files, like:

> .aux, .bbl, .blg, .brf, .dvi, .ilg, .ind, .log, .out, .nav, .snm,
>   .toc, .idx, .lof, .lot, .snm, .bcf, .run.xml, .vrb, ...

And recompile your `.tex` file:

```
latex  main.tex
bibtex main.aux
latex  main.tex
latex  main.tex
```

P.S. Look for some missing comma in .bib file.

Comment: Thank you!  I think that deleting the aux file and compiling twice did it for me.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  So TexStudio doesn't update the bibliography when you click compile in your main tex document, am I right?

Comment: This is so annoying that with TexStudio I have to delete all temporary files everytime I change the bibliography. It should not be so complicated.

Comment: You can rebuild the bibliography with Tools > Bibliography or by pressing F8 before compiling.

Answer (score 2):

If that doesn't help, make sure you don't have several .bib files with the same name in your path (and you're updating the wrong one).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer shouldn't be in this topic but i don't know were to put it. I lost a lot of time trying to figure out why I couldn't update the references in my `.bib` files, until I realize that I had to completely disable the UAC (Windows 8). To do this see:

http://www.eightforums.com/system-security/2434-disable-uac-completely.html

Hope it helps.